# PHP & cURL -- Wierd output

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web, curl

I'm mainly playing with PHP and cURL (the code includes some AJAX and HTML as well).

**Architecture:**

Front <--> Middle <--> Back <-->MySQL

**Description:**

1. In my front section I'm creating an AJAX object and doing a POST request with some data (JSON format) obtain from a Form in the HTML.
2. Data is sent to my middle server (PHP file). This file receives it and json_decodes it. Determines witch *switch case* to use and sends it to the back server using cURL.
3. Back server (PHP file) gets data from POST request and it json_decodes the data. It then proceeds to create MySQL connection checks if passwords match. If the passwords match it echos back a string saying "GRATNED".
4. Data is passed back to middle server and then to front section where AJAX receives it and displays the string.

So...

All of this works perfect. However, for some reason my data contains a 1 at the end. which messes up my Regular Expression in my JS file.

Can you guys please let me know what option do **cURL** (if that is the case) do I have to modify or what is it that I'm doing that I get that one(1) and how to remove it.

Thank you guys.

Attached is my code & and images of output...

**Front**

```
function whenSubmitt()
{
  //Get the data that I want to pass
  //JS Object
  var parameters = {"case":"login",
  "username":document.getElementById("username").value,
  "password":document.getElementById("password").value
  };

  //Make into JSON object
  parameters = JSON.stringify(parameters);

  //Create AJAX object
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var method = "POST";
  var url = "./front.php";

  //Open Connection
  xobj.open(method,url,true);
  xobj.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  //When Submit button is pressed
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == 200)
    {
      var respuestas = xobj.responseText;
      document.getElementById("msrv_answer").innerHTML = respuestas;
      //window.location.replace(respuestas[0]); //REDIRECTS TO NEW PAGE
    }
  };


  xobj.send(parameters);
}
```

**Front PHP**

```
<?php

function contact_middle_man($parameters)
{
 $url = "https://myurl/middle/middle.php";

 $obj = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_POST, strlen($parameters));
 curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
 curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //ALLOWS TO GET ANSWER BACK IN STRING FORMAT, AND DOES NOT OUTPUT ANSWER DIRECTLY.

 $ans = curl_exec($obj);

 curl_close($obj);

 return $ans;
}


/*RECEIVE DATA FROM WEB INTERFACE, USER*/
$indata = file_get_contents("php://input");

/*CONTACT MIDDLE MAN, USE CURL*/
$middle_answ = contact_middle_man($indata);

echo $middle_answ;
?>
```

**Middle PHP**

```
<?php

function http_post_back_server($url, $data)
{
    $obj = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_POST, strlen($data));
    curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $ans = curl_exec($obj);

    curl_close($obj);

    return $ans;
}

/*URL TO BACK SERVER*/
$url_myserver = "https://myurl/loginquery_v2_.php";

/*GLOBAL VARS*/
$back_ans ="";

/*RECEIVE DATA FROM POST REQUEST*/
$indata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($indata, true);


/*MAKE REQUEST TO SERVERS*/
switch($data["case"]){
    case "login":
        $back_ans = http_post_back_server($url_myserver,$indata);
        break;
    default:
        $back_ans="NADA";
        break;
}

/*ANSWER BACK TO FRON END*/
echo $back_ans;

?>
```

**Back PHP**

```
<?php

/*RECEIVING DATA FROM POST REQUEST */
$indata = file_get_contents("php://input");

/*DATA TO JSON OBJ*/
$indata = json_decode($indata, true);


/*CONNECTION TO DATABASE */
$conn=mysqli_connect(myusername, mypassword);

/*CHECKING DATABASE CONNECTIVITY */

if(mysqli_connect_error())
{ echo "Connection Error: ".mysqli_connect_error; }

/*GOOD CONNECTION ... CONTINUE */

$uname = $indata["username"];

$query="SELECT * FROM alpha WHERE username ='".$indata["username"]."'";

$db_output = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

/* CHECK QUERY RESULT */
if($db_output)
{

 /* FETCH RESULTS */
 while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_output))
 {

  /* COMPARE STORE PWD VS RECEIVED PWD */
  if($result["password"] == $indata["password"])
  {
    /*JSON OBJECT*/
    echo "ACCESS GRANTED";
  }

  /* PASSWORDS DOES NOT MATCH */
  else
  {
    /*JSON OBJECT*/
    echo "ACCESS DENY";
  }

 }
}

/*CLOSE DATABASE CONNECITON */

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

**PAGE WITH OUTPUT**

[image]

Thank you guys.

Comment: You need `curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` in your **Middle PHP**

Comment: @Nick, Hi NIck I added the option (and will leave it in my code) however I still get the 1 at the end of the string. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That should have got rid of the `1` as it was coming from `$ans` containing the return status of the curl (true => 1) from that curl request instead of the text (due to the lack of the `RETURNTRANSFER` option

Comment: @Nick, I understand but its still happening.. could there be something else that we are missing?

Comment: to be clear about Nick's correct suggestion, `curl_exec()` returns a boolean true (equiv 1) upon success unless the returntransfer option is set: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: @Andy there must be something else but I cannot see anything in the code you have posted.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, I see ... Randy is there a way to not echo back that 1 ?

Comment: @Nick, understood, thank you for you help Nick.

Comment: @Andy sorry I couldn't help more. It might help to debug if you change your `echo` statements to include the variable name, then you might be able to isolate the file which is inserting the `1` e.g. `echo "back_ans='$back_ans'";`

Comment: Like Nick, I see nothing else that would cause that. Why don't you var_dump() that variable and ensure it is NOT a `1`.

Comment: Understood, thank you guys. I will try your suggestions and try to debug the code.

Comment: You need to use `curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` in the FRONT PHP as well.  Didn't see that earlier.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, Front PHP has had the cURL option setup.

Comment: But you removed it from MIDDLE...it needs to be in both. Didn't mean to confuse.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, yes sir it worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nick thank you, you suggestion worked.

Comment: @Andy glad to hear it.

Comment: @Andy I've posted an answer just so the question can be closed and someone else visiting the question doesn't need to read the whole comment stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because in your **Middle PHP**, you are missing the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option in your curl call. As a result, `$ans` is assigned the value `true` (because the curl call is successful) and the output from the curl call (`ACCESS GRANTED`) is echo'ed into the output from **Middle PHP**, followed by `$back_ans`, which being true, when it is echo'ed produces a `1` in the output. Thus the string returned to **Front PHP** is `ACCESS GRANTED1`. You can fix this by adding this to **Middle PHP**:

```
curl_setopt($obj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Then `$ans` will be assigned the value `ACCESS GRANTED` instead of `true` and your output will be as expected.